# Translating Objective C call back to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, callback, game-center

I'm currently trying to translate a tutorial for game center from Objective C into Swift and I've hit roadblock. I've been searching for about an hour and haven't been able to find anything too helpful to help me translate this callback-method:

```
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
[viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
NSLog(@"Error finding match: %@", error.localizedDescription);
```

Sorry if this is easy (it probably is). I'm new to Swift and would love some help..
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has updated most of their documentation to have both Swift and Objective-C versions of the API, so you can view the [GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate methods there](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate/matchmakerViewController:didFailWithError:). This function would be:

```
func matchmakerViewController(viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController!, didFailWithError error:NSError!) {
    viewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    println("Error finding match: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```